How to set up a screensaver on 24.04
I had a screensaver on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. How to setup a screensaver on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS.
Thank you.

Are you using Wayland?

I've switched to Xorg, and it's fine. Thank you
